# swap the first element with the maximum element in the list-Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

So when a random list of numbers is entered into the function I want to switch the first element with the largest element.  Then return the new list.

```
def jumpMaximum(numList):
    max2=max(numList)
    a,b = int(numList[-len(numList)]),max
    numList[a],numList[b] = numList[b],numList[a]
    return numList
```

I cannot seem to figure out what is causing this to fail and not return the list.  All I need it to do is take the largest number and switch it with the first number.

Comment: Precisely how does it "fail"?  Why are you binding `b` to the function `max`?  Did you intend to write `a,b = ..., max2` instead?  Why not use `numList[0]` instead of `numList[-len(numList)]`?  Do you realize that `max(numList)` returns the largest element, not the *index* of the largest element?  For a start ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
index_max = a.index(max(a))
a[index_max], a[0] = a[0], a[index_max]
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugging the code that you posted here, I can see two mistakes:

- you've assigned `max` to `b`. But `max` is an in-built function and will not be accepted as  a valid index to a python list. But I guess that this was just a typo.
- using `a` and `b` as list indices, when they are respectively, the first and the maximum elements in the list.

Here's the debugged code:

```py
def jumpMaximum(numList):
 max2=max(numList)
 a,b = numList.index(int(numList[-len(numList)])),numList.index(max2)
 numList[a],numList[b] = numList[b],numList[a]
 return numList
```